# streamline code to update multiple datagridviews

Tags: datagridview

I have a program that populates and displays 20 datagridviews.  Each one displays the same data for a separate day.

I would like to have one common routine to handle the logic for all of the datagridviews.

This is the code I have (so far) for each of the datagridviews.  There is more logic to add and I would like to avoid replicating/maintaining it 20 times.

```
                SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();

                sReadBooking = "Select WorkOrder, FirstName, LastName, Vehicle, ServiceCar, RepairType from BOOKING where bookYear = @BKbookYear and bookMonth = @BKbookMonth and bookDay = @BKbookDay";

                SqlCommand ReadBooking = new SqlCommand(sReadBooking, con);
                ReadBooking.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BKbookDay", startDay);
                ReadBooking.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BKbookMonth", startMonth);
                ReadBooking.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BKbookYear", startYear);

                SqlDataReader myreader;
                con.Open();

                myreader = ReadBooking.ExecuteReader();

                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    WorkOrder = myreader["WorkOrder"].ToString();
                    FirstName = myreader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    LastName = myreader["LastName"].ToString();
                    Vehicle = myreader["Vehicle"].ToString();
                    ServiceCar = myreader["ServiceCar"].ToString();
                    RepairType = myreader["RepairType"].ToString();

                    iRow = monday1dataGridView.Rows.Add();
                    monday1dataGridView.Rows[iRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;

                    if (ServiceCar == "0")
                    {
                        ServiceCar = "No";
                    }
                    else if (ServiceCar == "1")
                    {
                        ServiceCar = "Yes";
                        monday1dataGridView.Rows[iRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ServiceCar = "Yes (Rental)";
                        monday1dataGridView.Rows[iRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
                    }

                    DataGridViewRow row = monday1dataGridView.Rows[iRow];

                    row.Cells["WorkOrder"].Value = WorkOrder;
                    row.Cells["CustomerName"].Value = LastName + ", " + FirstName;
                    row.Cells["Vehicle"].Value = Vehicle;
                    row.Cells["ServiceCar"].Value = ServiceCar;
                    row.Cells["RepairType"].Value = RepairType;
                    row.ReadOnly = true;
                }

                con.Close();
```

I have tried to pass the datagridview name to a routine but I have not found a way to make that work.